# okhttp3 onFailure detection

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I entered Okhttp (okhttp3) to retrieve data from the server. If the process of retrieving information from the server ends with "onFailure", I want to clarify why the process ends with "onFailure".  How can I find out if the domain is disconnected from the server (the server is down‚ the domain is without a server) or the user's Internet is on?  How can I do this on onFailure instead of checking the internet before starting okhttp3 and then starting the okhttp3 process?  I want to issue a corresponding Toast message accordingly.

**onFailure:**

```
client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback () { 
@Override 
public void onFailure (Call call, IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace ();
}
```

**how to:**

- The internet doesn't work
- Domain problem
- other...
  **Can I diagnose problems in onFailure and show a corresponding dialog?**

Comment: You can check exception variable that you receive in onFailure method. And make some conclusions. Sometimes you need to check cause of the Exception.

Comment: For example if it will be HttpException you should check status code, if it's 4xx error it means the issue on the client side, if it's 5xx error it means the issue on the server side.

Comment: Would you please show me a sample code? I can't find exactly the way you said. Please.

Comment: If you want handle network connection error you can find implementation here:
https://medium.com/programming-lite/retrofit-2-handling-network-error-defc7d373ad1

Comment: great but it didn’t help me. There is no Throwable in Okhttp3's onFailure! I have only IOException in onFailure.